# Sending an (asynchronous) message from one Spring Boot application to another using Spring Integration using annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have been messing around with Spring Integration, and I'd like to use its capabilities in a project. I have two different applications, one is a business-sided one, which when users do certain actions, should send messages to another application. The other application should receive these messages (using some kind of queue (rabbitmq or another) to handle big loads) and store them, so it can use it to create realtime statistics of a number of applications running.

These messages will just contain information of the actions of the users, for example "bought N of product X" or "Used searchbar for Y".

This scenario is of course pretty simple, but I don't want to use any kind of XML configuration in my Spring applications. The examples I have seen so far all rely on XML, but I want to use some kind of annotations instead.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Integration java dsl is already released which would serve your purpose.

A gentle introduction can be found at

https://dzone.com/articles/spring-integration-java-dsl

You can also checkout Camel (has a fluent dsl for EIP) which also gels well with spring